# Set the initialValue of a TextInput as a multi-line String

Tags: flutter, dart, widgetbook

I have a multi-line textInput in my application that looks like this:

```
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 5,
  minLines: 3,
  initialValue: object.textValue
)
```

It works fine when the user inputs new values.
However, when I need to load an existing value the input is not applying the line breaks.

This is an example of the text value I need to load:

```
"line 1\nline 2\n\nline 4"
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

How can I display the text respecting the line breaks?

Comment: I try your code. everything works fine.

Comment: what flutter version are you using?

Comment: Working on my side too. There is no modification of the object.textValue somewhere on your code?

Comment: flutter version: 3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

you can assign it with a `TextEditingController` :

```
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  controller.text = "test \n test \n";
```

Comment: What the difference with using initialValue? Linebreak are used the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4eeb18c12427186756461cf076a1bc56) to test and it worked, as many pointed out via comments.

So, reviewing my code I found the issue is introduced by a "knob" I'm using (with the [Widgetbook](https://pub.dev/packages/widgetbook) package):

```
context.knobs.text(...)
```

It is probably escaping the string before passing it to my widget.